# [Google]Are the sub and name and email from the userinfo endpoint confidential or public?

Tags: userinfo, pii

We use **https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo** to get user information, use name as a display name and sub as the google user id, we don't want to violate the PII, so want to confirm whether the sub and name and email are confidential or public? Whether we can expose sub and name and email to our end users(including user himself and other users).

Thanks

confirm whether the sub and name and email are confidential or public